# facing some css issue

Tags: php, html, css

Could anyone please tell me what went wrong for below code?

I am trying to display 18 products, 3 in each row. i am new to this CSS, not sure what went wrong, could you please check from below code:

**here is the output:**

```
http://your-guru.com/store/c/clothes/
```

**here is the code that displays the products:**

```
<!-- Product List -->
<div class="pl">
  [product.each]
  <div class="t1 col3">
   <ul style="display: block;" class="display thumb_view category_list">
    <li>
     <div class="content_block">
      <a href="[product.url]" title="[product.name]"  class="product_thumb" style="width:190px; height:180px">
       <img src="http://templatic.com/demos/ecommerce/wp-content/themes/eCommerce_child/images/sale.png" alt="" class="sale_img">[product.image direct='1' tag='1' width='190' height='180']
      </a>
      <div class="content">
       <h3>
        <a href="[product.url]" title="View details of [product.name]">[product.name]</a>
       </h3>
       <p class="sale_price">
       <?php if ($product->saleprice > 0 &&  $product->saleprice < $product->price) { ?>
       <div class="prc">
        <small>
         <span style="text-decoration: line-through; color:blue;">[product.currency mode='sign'][product.price]</span>
         &nbsp&nbsp
         <span style="font-weight: bold; color:red;">[product.currency mode='sign'][product.saleprice]</span>
        </small>
       </div>
       <?php } else { ?>
       <div class="prc">
        <small>
         <span style="font-weight: bold; color:blue;">[product.currency mode='sign'][product.price]</span>
        </small>
       </div>    
       <?php } ?>
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>  <!-- content block #end --> 
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>  <!-- t1 col3 #end --> 
  [/product.each]
  <div class="clearingdiv"></div>
 </div> <!-- /Product List -->
```

Please tell me what went wrong?

Comment: i think their is no fault in css any other issue in your code

Comment: @SahilPopli it's the CSS for sure. At least he's not using tables :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, the HTML-MarkUp is a bit bloated, difficult to maintain. Second, you should not use css inline.

Your problem is about floating and no equal heights of your products. When you give the following selector `#view .col3` a height like 370px you can see that the products are floating nicely. 
So, you have to choose how you set your height.

- static height with enough space
- stripping the product-titles
- setting the height of .col3 via javaScript
- ...

Comment: Right on the button. The 1 product in the 3rd row shows this quite clearly. Needs a set height for each product, or a *clear* element after/between each row.

Comment: @Spontifixus  wow! thanks alot bro! May I know how did U identified that i should set height , then I get my desired output, btw where did u find #view .col3 in my source code..? Just to learn...

Comment: @John: Just to clarify: I did not write that answer, I just improved its formatting. So credit goes to @rxtxr!

Comment: @Spontifixusiam sorry I was confused..

Comment: @rxtxr: thanks alot bro! May I know how did U identified that i should set height , then I get my desired output, btw where did u find #view .col3 in my source code..? Just to learn..

Answer (score 0):

...

HI now add `overflow:hidden` of your `#wrapper` id

as like this

```
#wrapper{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: as far as I know I didnt used wrapper id anywhere.. could u pls be bit breif, where ur referring to..?

Comment: now add this css in your stylesheet anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Your li height are different or auto and float:left

Forced solution (not recommended):

```
#content ul.thumb_view li {
  border-bottom: none;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 300px;/*you might try to force the height if you want to also*/
}
```

Recommended solution:

[Masonry Plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/)